# Fetching data from TableViewController's CoreData database

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a TableViewController using the CoreData database.
I have another UIviewController from which I want to read the TableViewController's database.
What I did was as follow.

```
//In UIviewController
-(NSArray *)fetchRecordedDatainsqldatabase
{
    // construct a fetch request

    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackerList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    // Create the sort descriptors array.
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"descript" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    // return the result of executing the fetch request
    return [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];}
```

I have a property of

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

But managedObjectContext is always nil, at the line
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackerList" 
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

So the program is always crash when it reaches to that line.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Where do you create the NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: In the ViewDidLoad as _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

Comment: The thing is if I put  _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; in the ViewDidLoad, _managedObjectContext is not nil. But still crash when the program reaches to the line NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackerList" 
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can use the `managedObjectContext` provided to you in the stub code in `AppDelegate`. If thats the case you can use:

```
AppDelegate *appD = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then instead of the line:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackerList" 
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

use:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrackerList" 
inManagedObjectContext:appD.managedObjectContext];
```

and you should replace the return statement to this:

```
return [appD.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

If you are creating your own `NSManagedObjectContext` object, then you should be setting its `persistentStoreCoordinator` (which in turns need the managed object model and set the persistent store type).

You can see how to do all this in `AppDelegate.m` , if you have checked 'use core-data' when creating the project.

Anyway in your case, you already are using a managedObjectContext successfully in your first view controller. So you just need to get the same object over in the second view controller.

For your method to work, you just have to add one line at the top of the code block you provided:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to show what you have to do for the method to work, since you are using the managedObjectContext provided by AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks, yours is the best approach.In this way I can access the existing database.Now I use your approach and it works. But for MasterViewController, it has its own NSManagedObjectContext and can't find how it links to the AppDelegate's NSManagedObjectContext.Anyway thanks.

Comment: Great. If you think this is the solution you can accept my answer/give it an upvote if you don't mind. :)

Comment: There will be a tick mark next to each answer. That accepts that particular answer as the solution to your question. (You can do this for only one answer). Then there is an up and down arrow near the answer, if you found the answer useful you can give it an upvote - the up arrow (can be done on multiple answers).

Answer (score 0):

**Managed Object Context** needs to be initialized with a **Persistent Store Coordinator** and which needs a **Managed Object Model**. XCode used to provide a boiler plate code for all these implementation in AppDelegate.

As an alternative solution you can try using [MagicalRecord](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CGAQFjAH&url=http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/&ei=Rw4zUdCbIoXXrQenpIAw&usg=AFQjCNEOzUWDICJB_m830sGlyGXvr9xhng&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk&cad=rja)

You can set up core data by

`[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"Database.sqlite"];`

And you can fetch all the trackerlist values in a context by

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext];
[TrackerList findAllSortedBy:@"descript" ascending:YES inContext:context];
```

Following link would guide you better 
 [How to make programming in Core Data pleasant](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CGAQFjAH&url=http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/&ei=Rw4zUdCbIoXXrQenpIAw&usg=AFQjCNEOzUWDICJB_m830sGlyGXvr9xhng&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk&cad=rja)

Comment: Yeah in AppDelegate, all objects related to the CoreData are initialised. But In MasterViewController, it has only -@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
-@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; and I even don't see init for managedObjectContext. I am confuse how it is implemented in MasterViewController.

Comment: @Bryanyan: How did you get your managedObjectContext in the MasterViewController? Is it the first view controller or the second?

Comment: managedObjectContext is already created in first view controller by XCode when I choose Master/Detail Application for the new project.